# facing error for calling member function with pointer

Tags: c++

As i have read that if we create object through pointer, it wont delete automatically. but when i am calling member function with pointer its giving error

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
protected:
    int i;
public:
    Base(){}
    Base(int a)     { i = a; }
    virtual void display()
    { cout << "I am Base class object, i = " << i << endl; }
    ~Base(){
        cout<<"tsp";
    }
};

int main()
{
    //Base b(33);
    {
    Base *u=new Base() ;
    }
    u->display();
    //delete u;
    return 0;
}
```

O/P:'u' was not declared in this scope but still the memory exist

Comment: If i am removing the scope it is calling the funtion

Comment: The variable `u` and the object you allocated with `new` are separate things with independent existence.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer is not being deleted, but `u` goes out of scope when the block it is declared in ends; `u` is only available within that block.  Therefore, calling `u->display()` is an error because there is no `u` variable in scope anymore.

Note that because it's not automatically deleted (going out of scope *is not* the same thing as being deleted), you are leaking the memory allocated by the `Base` object.

To put it another way, `u` points to a `Base` object but *it is not itself the object.*  The pointer can go away, but the object can still exist.  It's like if I had someone's business card and threw it away.  Their phone number or email address don't cease to exist just because I threw away my record of it.

"`u` goes out of scope" is throwing away the business card.

"`delete u`" is... disconnecting the phone line on the business card, I guess.

Contrast this with the following code, using a smart pointer:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "top\n";

    {
        std::unique_ptr<Base> u{new Base()};
    }

    std::cout << "bottom\n";
}
```

In this case, when `u` goes out of scope, the smart pointer will be destructed and the `Base` allocation *will* be freed (you will see the output `tsp` before you see the output `bottom`).

Comment: So If i will use smart pointer , then i dont need to delete the memory created during new Base()

Comment: @TUHINSUBHRAPANDA Correct, the smart pointers will delete it for you. Each smart pointer type (`unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, etc.) has different conditions for deleting the underlying object, and can be used in different circumstances (e.g. `unique_ptr`s cannot be copied, but `shared_ptr`s can).